# Getting URL from a named credential

Tags: apex, callout, namedcredentials

Is there a way to get a named credential URL into a variable in apex?

It looks like the named credential path only works for the setEndpoint method.

Comment: what you are trying to achieve taking named credential into a variable?

Comment: Basically, the callout returns a token. The method needs to return the URL plus that token in it and I don't want to have to store the URL in multiple places

Comment: you can store in protected custom settings or custom metadata type

Comment: I know that I can, but it seems ridiculous that you would need to store it in 2 places

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the `SOAP API Developer Guide`, the [`NamedCredential`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_namedcredential.htm) object has a field named `Endpoint`:

> **Description**
>   The root URL of the endpoint.

So you should be able to do a query like:

```
SELECT DeveloperName, Endpoint FROM NamedCredential
```

Comment: It's working fine with `New Legecy` Named Credential, but if we create using <New> button, then it's not returning EndPoint.